# Hardware error during system boot

Tags: manjaro

Everything seems to be working correctly, but during the loading process of Manjaro Linux I see hardware errors shown on below picture (I have disabled splash screen).

Currently I use kernel 4.13.11-1.

Update: Errors do not show up when using kernel 4.9.61-3.

What is the cause of those errors and how can I get rid of them?

[image: errors]

Comment: The 'mce' in those lines stands for 'machine check exception' and according to this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine-check_exception), it sounds like it might be fairly serious.

Comment: Questions: 1) What hardware are you using? 2) Is this a custom kernel you have built, or a pre-packaged generic kernel? 3) Have you tried installing/booting from any other distros? If so, do you get the same error messages?

Comment: @Time4Tea Interestingly, when I switched back to kernel 4.9(.61-3), those errors disappeared. I use pre-packaged kernels available through "Manjaro Settings Manager" – they are just installed by pacman. What do you mean by what hardware do I use? I could post somewhere the effect of some "hardware info" command if it'd be helpful.

Comment: Does [that article](http://www.advancedclustering.com/act_kb/what-are-machine-check-exceptions-or-mce/) help? Errors not showing up with the other kernel maybe because of (1) no mce reporting in older kernel, or (2) different code through boot doesn't cause that particular problem to happen.

Comment: Problem can be in Manjaro. You can convert your Manjaro to `Arch` or boot up live `Arch` iso. Check if MCE errors appear in it.

Comment: Have you tried using intel-ucode? This may be a superficial error.

Comment: @jdwolf What do you mean? Could you be more specific?

Comment: @Luke Basically the linux kernel can do microcode updates to the processor if its included before the initrd. The error you see could be the kernel trying to use the CPU in a way only meant for an updated microcode.

Actually both AMD and Intel cpus do this. But AMD works automatically whereas intel is loaded manually. So I'll assume if thats it you must have an intel.

Comment: @jdwolf Honestly it's the first time I hear about the need to update processor firmware

Comment: @Luke it happens automatically most of the time thats why.

Comment: @Luke https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Microcode Try following that and you can rule it out at least. It can't really hurt much if its not it.

Comment: @Luke Also the BIOS/UEFI will ALSO update the CPU firmware so you could also update your BIOS instead. But since BIOS support tends to be awful it might be better to have linux do it.

Comment: This is one the the cases that a photo of text is acceptable. However can you ensure that it is in focus, so I can read it.